# Simple android binary crashing with zlib

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, zlib

I made a simple android executable with CMake that links with the native zlib on the ndk. Everything compiles correctly, but when calling `deflateInit` I get a segmentation fault.

Here is the code:

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <zlib.h>

int main()
{
    z_stream strm;
    deflateInit(&strm, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
    std::cout << "it works!" << std::endl;
}
```

And the corresponding `CMakeLists.txt`

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(zlib-on-android)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)

set_target_properties(main
  PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC ZLIB::ZLIB)
```

I then compile with the following command:

`cmake -H. -Bbuild -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=~/android-ndk-r17b -DCMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE=c++_static -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=16 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang`

Everything works fine. Then I do the following:

```
cd build
adb push main /data/local/tmp/.
adb shell
shell@device:/ $ cd /data/local/tmp
shell@device:/ $ ./main
[1] + Stopped (signal)     ./main
```

Does anyone know the reason? I am having a lot of trouble trying to hook up gdb with this executable. Since the same code works on my  Macosx, I cannot understand why it does not work on android.

#### EDIT

For some reason the same code crashes on Macosx (the one that worked was a similar code). This is the error: `bus error ./main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out that setting `z_stream` to zero fixes the problem.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    z_stream strm;
    std::memset(&strm, 0, sizeof(z_stream));
    deflateInit(&strm, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
    std::cout << "it works!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The real issue is that the deflate function reads the internals of the stream on input.  Obviously you gave the function a structure with random garbage.  Setting the structure to all zero initializes the members that the function reads to correct values.

Comment: The [documentation here](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html##Basic) states that the fields in `z_stream` are to be initialized when calling `deflateInit`.  In general, when any API wants a pointer to a struct, always read the documentation carefully as to whether the function will read various members of the struct to do housekeeping.